# Display batch script output in a .txt file

Tags: batch-file, logging

I have this piece of code: For /R "C:\Test\" %%G IN (Downloads) do del /F /Q "%%G"
Which starts looking from C:\Test\ for the Downloadfolder and than empties it.

I'd like to log the process of the script emptying those folders in a .txt file, any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code doesn't do what you say it will do.

Comment: it does... , when i execute it it deletes all files in the download folder looking from C:\Test

Comment: It doesn't do it in the way you state - try launching your command above with `echo` before the `del`.  I tested it to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Append

```
>>yourfilename.txt
```

to the `del` command.